# The file format and extension doesn't match excel while downloading from .net website

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net

I have created an ASP.net website with the back end code in Vb I have generated a button to save the contents in an excel file but when Excel tries to open the file I get the following message.

*** Format and extension of 'FileName.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?**

I am attaching my aspx.vb code

```
 Protected Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Response.Clear()
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.xls")
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"
        Dim stringWrite As New System.IO.StringWriter()
        Dim htmlWrite As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite)
        GridView5.RenderControl(htmlWrite)
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString())
        Response.[End]()
    End Sub
```

Comment: This is happening because you are attaching HTML and giving it the extension of .xls. Fortunately, Excel can convert the HTML for a gridview to a readable spreadsheet. Unfortunately, it's a warning that Excel is set to give and I haven't found a way around it aside from creating a native .xls file.

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/drafts/98280) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Comment: @VDWWD thanks for your feedback but if others want to access the Excel file from a different computer and if they do not have the EPPlus how would they open the file without prompting the message.

Comment: EPPlus generates a real excel file on the server. The clients just download a real excel file instead of a html page.

Comment: I have added the EPPlus via the NuGet Package Manager and when I download the file it is still giving me the same message.

Comment: Did you change your code to use EPPlus?